# How can a Simulink model discover it's own filename and path?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I would like to display some information about a Simulink model, without first knowing the filename. The information will be displayed in the model itself.

Something similar, [mfilename](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mfilename.html), is available for MATLAB programs. Is there an equivalent for Simulink models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Edric I found `bdroot`, which gives the system name.
Passing this to `which` makes Matlab find the model using it's search path.

So the solution is `model_path = which (bdroot);`

*One problem is that if you have shadowed files this method may give the incorrect answer.*

Comment: This doesn't work if model is not located in the path

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be more reliable to get the model parameter in case there is more than one matching model in your path:

```
model_path = get_param(bdroot, 'FileName');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `gcs` http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/gcs.html